# RIP Glenn Randers-Pehrson

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217526/smallest-image-containing-one-of-every-rgb-color) jogged my memory that we have an expert in our ranks who might give a brilliant answer to this question - [Glenn Randers-Perhson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17193/glenn-randers-pehrson):

> Coauthor of PNG spec, developer/maintainer of libpng, on development teams for ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick. Author of pngcrush. Maintains PNG support in Firefox. Retired, father of four, grandfather of fifteen.

After a little googling, I was saddened to find that [Glenn passed away 2 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/p/png-mng/mailman/message/36447670/).

Thank you Glenn for your work on PNG - a vital part of the web as used by literally billions.

Thank you also for your .SE contributions, including those to codegolf.  In the few interactions I had with Glenn, he was a real gentleman, greatly knowledgeable and always helpful.

Comment: [Glenn's answers here on CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17193/glenn-randers-pehrson?tab=answers)